# How to programmatically add dialogs with primefaces

Tags: jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I want to display some data through primefaces datalist component. To achieve this I have an arrayList like `ArrayList<Person>`.

The person class looks something like this

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private ArrayList<String> hobbies;
}
```

To display the data I'm using the following code:

```
<p:dataList value="{gameBean.persons}" var="person" itemType="disc">  
    Name: #{person.getName()}, Age: #{person.getAge()}, 
    <h:link value="Hobbies" onclick="dlg1.show();" />
</p:dataList>
```

What I want do do now, is to create a link that opens a dialog when clicked:

```
 <p:dialog header="Hobbies" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true"height="100">
    //iterate through hobbies list to print it 
 </p:dialog>
```

So far this is working because I've hard coded the dialog as mentioned above in the xhtml file.

This method is of course not working for a dynamic amount of persons as I can not hard code the dialogs and the links. My question is, how can I create this dialogs programmatically and assign the right widgetVar variable to the onClick method of the Links?

Any help is highly apprechiated, 
cheers Nikolaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataList value="{gameBean.persons}" var="person" itemType="disc">  
        Name: #{person.getName()}, Age: #{person.getAge()}, 
        <p:column>
            <p:commandLink value="Hobbies" actionListener="#{gameBean.onPersonSelect(person)}" 
                       oncomplete="dlg1.show();" update=":form:hobbiesDlg" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataList>

    <p:dialog header="Hobbies" id="hobbiesDlg" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true"height="100">
        //iterate through hobbies of gameBean.person to show here
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GameBean {
   private Person person;

   public void onPersonSelect(Person person) {
      this.person = person;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is the right way. Unfortunately i got the following error message when i tried it:                   Dez 30, 2011 8:01:24 PM org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils findClientIds
Information: Cannot find component with identifier "hobbiesDlg" in view.

Comment: hmmm... suppose you have `<h:form id="myForm">`, you can try changing `update="hobbiesDlg"` to `update="myForm:hobbiesDlg"` or `update=":myForm:hobbiesDlg"`.

Comment: You're right. now the update is working but unfortunately there is another issue. It seems that the actionlistener is never fired. I have tried to change the action listener to this stlye ( actionListener="#{} ) but still it's not working.  Edit: It seems that there are some problems when firing the action within the datalast respectively the form because i tried to put the link outside the form and it worked... Ideas?

Comment: Sry about the `#{}`, I forgot to type it :). Let me think a while for the 2nd problem

Comment: np, thanks for your help. Actually I think, that there are too many "sublevels" of elements, because my strucutre looks like this form->fieldset->datalist->Links... When placing the link direct under the form it is working...

Comment: @NikolausHartlieb I found the problem. It turned out that you have to put your link inside `<p:column>` for it to work.

Comment: thanks, now it's working. One last thing: you have to pass the parameter (in this case person) through <f:attribute name="orderbook" value="#{orderBook}" /> within the commandLink tag.

Comment: update=":myForm:hobbiesDlg"  made my day <3