# How do you create a dialog programmatically in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How do you create a dialog programmatically in Primefaces?

I have a page named tree.xhtml with a `<p:tree/>` and a tree node with a right-click contextmenu option that selects a `bean.edit()` method.

When the user clicks on the `bean.edit()` method, I want the method to display a dialog programmatically and I want to be able to create input elements or a drop down combo box with more than one element and a submit button. I have looked at the User's guide and I do not see such an example so I am hoping you guys can show me how to do it here.

Many thanks in advance.

Joe

Comment: Do you really want to "design" the dialog programmatically, or would you just like call a method in the bean which tells the dialog to show up?

Comment: I want to create the dialog and its children programmatically.

Comment: helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152789/create-primefaces-dialogs-dynamically/26485334#26485334

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger the showup of a dialog programmatically you can use the `visible` attribute to do so:

Your dialog in xhtml:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dialog id="myDialog" header="The Dialog" visible="#{backingBean.showDialog}">  
    ...
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Your backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BackingBean{
    private boolean showDialog;

    public void displayDialog() {
        showDialog = true;
    }

    public boolean getShowDialog() {
        return showDialog;
    }
}
```

Your trigger e.g. a CommandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show dialog" action="#{backingBean.displayDialog}" update=":myForm" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Flash but I am not just asking how to display a dialog programmatically.  What I want to know is how to create one programmatically, and with all its children programmatically.  So, I want to know how to create a dialog and lets say a form and an input box, combo box, and submit button programmatically.  This way, if I need to create a dialog with just an input box I can and if I need to create a dialog with a combo box and 5 elements, I can, and if the elements change for the combo box, then I can handle that too since I am doing it all programmatically.